# filter columns in a dataframe based on max value/ least ranked value of a different column in the same dataframe

Tags: r, select, dataframe, dplyr, filtering

i have a data frame as below. Its just an example. The real data set is much bigger.

```
Hospital    State   Mortality   Rank 
aaa          AK        9.7       1  
bbb          AK        10.5      2
ccc          AK        11.3      3
ddd          AK        11.5      4
eee          AL         8.7      1
ggg          AL         9.1      2
hhh          AL         9.3      3 
mmm          AR         9.9      1
nnn          AR         10.2     2
ooo          AR         10.4     3
ppp          AZ         7.5      1
qqq          AZ         8.7      2
```

for reprodusability purpose the code to get the above dataframe is below.

`df <- data.frame(Hospital=c("aaa","bbb","ccc","ddd","eee","ggg","hhh","mmm","nnn","ooo","ppp","qqq"),State=c("AK","AK","AK","AK","AL","AL","AL","AR","AR","AR","AZ","AZ"), Mortality=c(9.7,10.5,11.3,11.5,8.7,9.1,9.3,9.9,10.2,10.4,7.5,8.7),Rank=c(1,2,3,4,1,2,3,1,2,3,1,2))`

when i pass an argument called worst, i want to extract the Hospital and state column from the dataframe which has the lowest ranking.

the expected output should be something like this

```
Hospital    State

ddd          AK       
hhh          AL        
ooo          AR       
qqq          AZ
```

even if i could get a outcome as below, i can use the select function of the dplyer and get the above expected result.

```
Hospital    State   Mortality   Rank 

ddd          AK        11.5      4
hhh          AL         9.3      3 
ooo          AR         10.4     3
qqq          AZ         8.7      2
```

i made use of the below code to get a list of the least ranked value from each group. The object worst1 has a list of all the least ranked value of each group.

```
worst<-df %>% group_by(State) %>% summarise(max = max(Rank))
worst1 <- as.vector(worst[,2, drop=FALSE])
```

wondering if i could use this to extract my expected output or if there is a easier way to directly get the desired output.

i tried using this `df[df$Rank %in% worst1,]` but i dint get any result. Any form of help would be much useful. Thanks in advance

Answer (score 2):

Here is a much shorter solution, with no need to create a separate data frame. Just use dplyr::top_n

```
df %>% group_by(State) %>% top_n(1, Rank)
```

Comment: Thank @NiclasRudolfson for this nice trick , I didn't know the `top_n` function. @ Sai Ram, likewise, `df %>% group_by(State) %>% top_n(-1, Rank)` will give you the least ranked hospital per state.

Comment: top_n() will select the row with the highest value for Rank in each group, so will give you the "worst" hospital. If you want the best, I would recommend `top_n(1, desc(Rank)` rather than `top_n(-1, Rank)`

Comment: @SaiRam Please accept one of the answers here if they are correct and useful to your question.

Answer (score 0):

One option is to change the name of the variable in `summarise()` and then `inner_join()` `df` and `worst`.

```
worst <- df %>%
  group_by(State) %>%
  summarise(Rank = max(Rank))

worst1 <- inner_join(df, worst, by = c("State", "Rank"))
```